# Subscripts in math mode independent of the text that comes before

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Here there is a problem I don't know how to solve.

If we write `$D^{*} _{text}$` what happens is that `text`is going to be subscripted below `*`, even if we have put a space between `D^{*}`and `text`.

How can we achieve the situation where `text`is subcripted (relatively to `D^{*}`), but not being below `*`(as if it is a text that actually follows).

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty subformula `{}` can be used as anchor for the subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}
$D^{*} {}_{\text{text}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The example also uses `\text` from `amsmath` or `amstext` to avoid mathematical typesetting for a subscript containing text.

An alternative for text subscript with a newer LaTeX provides `\textsubscript`. Its implementation uses a math subformula, thus the explicit empty braces are not needed in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$D^{*} \textsubscript{text}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Encase what is to be subscripted (here: `D^{*}`) in braces:

```
${D^{*}}_{text}$
```

[image]

Also, if `text` really is text, consider `\text{text}` (needs the `amsmath` package).